# cant install libgmail in python

Tags: python, libgmail

i'm a newbie in python , and trying to install libgmail ..
this is what i get :

```
C:\libgmail-0.1.11>setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\libgmail-0.1.11\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libgmail
  File "C:\libgmail-0.1.11\libgmail.py", line 96
    exec data in {'__builtins__': None}, {'D': lambda x: result.append(x)}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i think that the libgmail is a bit older then my python version , but dont know how to solve it, please help :-)

thanks in advance
Amitos80

Comment: Looks like your Python version is too old.

Comment: @Noufal: I would guess it's too *new*

Comment: @user349063: This is a bit tangential. I used libgmail to access a Gmail inbox and found that it did not work. I later learned that libgmail is not actively maintained. Finally I switched to Python's imaplib and used it successfully to do what I wanted.

Comment: Eli : Correct. Mea culpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? It's possible it's 3.x which doesn't understand `exec` as a statement (in Python 3, `exec`, like `print` became a function and is no longer a special keyword/statement).

The solution is to either find a port of `libgmail` to Python 3, or install Python 2.7 for yourself instead.

Answer (score 0):

What version of libgmail are you installing?
I succesfully installed [mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.2.2)( on which libgmail was depending) and [libgmail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgmail/files/) by [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) minute ago.